# Can a right-continuous stochastic process be predictable?

Tags: stochastic-processes

I know that a stochastic process is said to be predictable if it's measurable with respect to the *predictable* $\sigma$-field $\mathcal P$, namely the $\sigma$-field generated by all left-continuous adapted processes.

I furthermore know that if $X$ is a càdlàg process then $X(t-)$,  (the left hand limit) is a predictable process.

Nevertheless I have some difficulties discerning whether a right-continuous process (the process being non-continuous) can be predictable or not.

Could you give me a hand with this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about $X_t=0$ for all $t$?

Comment: predictability will hold for sure for all continuous processes since a continuous process is by definition left-continuous. I mean some process which is right continuous and whose left limit does not necessarily exists.

Comment: Take $X_t=f(t)$ where $f$ is a non-random cadlag function.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In fact, stochastic processes of the form $Z 1_{[\tau,\infty)}$ where $Z \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau-}$ and $\tau$ is a predictable stopping time generate the predictable sigma-algebra (see [here](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2016/11/22/predictable-processes/)), and any such process is right-continuous.

Comment: You got a point,   One additional question,  assume we are working with generic right-continuous processes, in order to have predictability do we need the left-limit to exits?

Comment: No, just take a deterministic process which is right-continuous but doesn't have left limits